Should I use Schedule 80 PVC or metal for a riser and weatherhead?
I am replacing an old disconnect in a small well house.
Does the riser need to be Rigid Metal?
I have a new 1 1/4 sch 80 with Weatherhead in PVC.
Wires-
New setup: (2) 4 gauge, and I am unsure about the neutral size.
Existing setup: There is no neutral from the main panel (170 ft away), just 2 hots.

This is the current wire:

Well House

TIA.

The steel/bare cable takes the tension of the wires.  So schedule 80 will probably be okay.  Having no ground is a separate issue.

@crip659 I added a ground (I think I will add a second rod). I am also connecting the neutral to the aluminum cable that holds the 2 hots in the air.

If just powering the pump, a neutral is just a waste/not needed.  Neutral is just needed for 120v lights/radios/power tools/man cave.

@crip659, yes, I added a subpanel, powering other things now.

You will need to find out how much extra power you might need.  Most people will use the minimum size/gauge wire as possible.  If the pump needs 20 amps, then the minimum is 12 gauge, maybe 10 gauge with the distance.  A radio or a couple lights are no biggy.  Add some power tools and life could get interesting.

@crip659 pump and now, a camper and an extra 15 amp circuit. 75 amps.
